# Flask print logs in an imported class

Tags: python, flask, web, logging

I have a simple flask app

```
from flask import Flask
from base import MyClass

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    base = MyClass()
    base.my_method()
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"
```

`base.py`

```
import logging

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class MyClass:

    def my_method(self):
        LOG.debug("debug logs here")
```

I cannot see the logs from `MyClass` when call my_method

I was expecting to see the logs `debug logs here` on my terminal.

Comment: Is your logging level set appropriately? The default log level is WARNING which won't show DEBUG messages.

Comment: @kindall I tried LOG.error("debug logs here") worked!
but when tried to set the logger level to debug with app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) it still not working do you know how to change the level correctly